# Show the value if it is common to all variables

Tags: c++, string, mfc, edit

I am trying to get something working and am struggling to go about it. I am guessing this probably is done in windows but I am not sure on what its called. Basically you know in windows we notice that when we select some files, press right click and then windows shows common options to those files.

Question:
I have lets say an edit box that can contain a string value: "*xyz*" and is taken from a list of strings that are available in a combobox. Now, I have a button that can select some strings in the combobox(this works fine till here). I would like to show the edit box with the string value, if all the selected ones have the same string value. So, if all the selected edit boxes have a common value "*xyz*", then show the edit box with the value "*xyz*" and don't show otherwise. Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop through the selected items and compare them to the first one. If any differ, hide the edit box, otherwise set its text to the value and show it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. Was just wondering if there were any windowsy functions to do that. Doesn't look like there are. Thanks though.